# Does not get to get the balance amount for the near wallet

Tags: python, rpc, nearprotocol

I want to get some sums of my wallet balance using 'near-api-py' lib on 'Account' tab of wallet profile(https://wallet.near.org/profile):
Wallet balance(NEAR, USD) - near_provider.get_account(account_id) - at the moment, I can only get this amount by all the methods described.

```
def get_account(self):
    state = near_provider.get_account(account_id)
    print(state)
    return state['amount'], state['block_hash'], state['block_height'], state['locked'], state['storage_paid_at'], \
           state['storage_usage']
```

`state['locked'], state['storage_paid_at']` - outputs 0. Why? I don't understand.
I need to get the following amounts:

1. Reserved for storage(NEAR, USD)
2. Reserved for transactions(NEAR, USD)
3. Available balance(NEAR, USD) - at least get this amount!!!!!

Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_balance()` method from `py-near`

Docs: https://py-near.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html

Comment: this method does not return the available balance, only the total